# How to divide $6^{4/6}$ by $6^{6/8}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How do you resolve this: base 6 and exponent 4/6 divided by base 6 and exponent 6/8?

Comment: Have you tried subtracting the exponents?

Comment: If you mean $\frac{6^{\frac{4}{6}}}{6^{\frac{6}{8}}}$ then use the fact that $\frac{a^b}{a^c}=a^{b-c}$

Comment: Ok, but when you subtract do you have to cross multiply first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the exponent rule $\dfrac{x^a}{x^b}=x^{a-b}$.

$$\dfrac{6^{4/6}}{6^{6/8}}=6^{4/6-6/8}=6^{-1/12}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt[12]{6}}$$

Comment: Why was this deleted and reposted?  The original mistake had already been edited out.

Comment: So you would have to cross multiply to obtain the results?

Comment: No, the result is after the last $=$-sign.